# make install - how to use wget, not curl

Tags: root, git, make, wget, curl

I do not have root access on my Ubuntu but want to install `git`. I was following this [tutorial](http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/) but when running `make` or `make install` it says `curl` is not installed.

**Can I use `wget` instead if this is a `make` config setting?**

Answer (score 1):

No, git actually wants libcurl and not cur itself. You can't compie git without it. Why not ask your sysadmin to install git?